# Shiny dashboard with two sidepanels and a plot

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyapps

I'm trying to get a Rshiny code to display two panels on the left hand side (one for file input and the other to action plot) and a plot on the right hand side, but I got the following error:

```
Error in match.arg(position) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
```

Here is the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(pheatmap)

# Define UI for dataset viewer app ----
ui <- fluidPage(

           # App title ----
       titlePanel("plot"),

# Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
   sidebarLayout(

# Sidebar panel for inputs ----
   sidebarPanel("Sidebar panel",

  # Input: Selector for choosing dataset ----
  fileInput("file1", "Choose CSV File",
              accept = c(
                "text/csv",
                "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                ".csv")
    ),
    tags$hr(),
    checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE)
),

   # tags$hr(),

     sidebarPanel('get heatmap',
             actionButton('getHmap', 'get heatmap')
),

# Main panel for displaying outputs ----
mainPanel("Plot",
          #column(6, 
             plotOutput("themap"),
             tableOutput("table.output"))
          #)
    )

 )


server = function(input, output, session) {
  a <- reactive({
    inFile <- input$file1
    if (is.null(inFile))
      return(NULL)
tbl <- read.csv(inFile$datapath, header=input$header) #, sep=input$sep,  dec = input$dec)
return(tbl)
  })

  output$table.output <- renderTable({
    a()
  })

  plotdata <- eventReactive(input$getHmap, {
    a <- as.matrix(a()[-1])
    row.names(a) <- a()$ID
    a[is.na(a)] <- 0
    a
   })

  output$themap = renderPlot({ 
    pheatmap(plotdata())
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I'm new to Rshiny. Can someone help me find the cause of this problem please?

Comment: There is a parenthesis  in a bad place in `ui`. Take one of the two last parenthesis in the `ui` and move it just after the `actionButton` (where there is already a parenthesis and a comma). Hint to see where this sort of error comes from: put large parts of your app in comments (ctrl + shift + c on selected lines) to narrow the problem down. For example, I put the whole `server` part in comments at the beginning to see that the problem came from the `ui`, and then commented and un-commented several parts of the `ui` to find the problem

Comment: The problem with parentheses won't solve the problem - the real problem is that sidbar layout only accepts one sidebar and one mainpanel if you want to do something else you need to use a more flexible layout such as fluidpage und use columns to structure the dashboard

Comment: Error disappeared after applying the fix suggested by @bretauv , however the the two panels are on top side by side, and the plot at the bottom. Probably, suggestion by Bertil Baron may help further. Thanks guys.